# How to increase performance of select query if row by row calculation is required?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, procedure

I have a table as follows:

- PK,
- Date,
- Hour (0-23),
- Transaction Id (Foreign key),
- Price,
- Volume

There is 3 year data (365x24x3 = 26280 hours), for each transaction. And, I got 5000 of them (and growing) at the moment.

I am trying to calculate weighted average ( SUM(P_Transaction1xV_Transaction1+ P_Transaction2xV_Transaction2+ … + P_Transaction5000xV_Transaction5000)/ SUM(V_Transaction1+ V_Transaction2+…+ V_Transaction5000) for each hour (for each 26280).

We tried following options but could not manage to decrease the run time significantly.

**OPTION 1:**

Data table:
PK
Date
Transaction Id (Foreign key)
Price1, Price2, … , Price24
Volume1, Volume2, … Volume24

Indexed columns : Transaction Id, Date
Stored procedure is used.

**OPTION 2:**

Data table 1:
PK
Date
Hour (0-23)
Transaction Id (Foreign key)
Volume

Data table 2:
PK
Date
Hour (0-23)
Transaction Id (Foreign key)
Price

Indexed columns : Transaction Id, Date, Hour
Stored procedure is used.

**OPTION 3:**
As I explained at the beginning.

I am wondering if there is a better approach as far as data model, indexing or etc… is concerned. In order to increase the performance as much as possible.

Comment: Option1, with 24 price columns and 24 volume columns is a mess. Avoid it!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using!?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition (64-bit)

Comment: Have you tried to express it as a single SQL rather than a stored procedure? Sometimes it can be much faster. Alternatively you could try to use temporary tables for intermediate data and split the job into parts, that may be faster. I would start with a single SQL and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to find out an aggregate "for each hour", your starting point should be a `group by date, hour`

```
select date, hour, sum(price * volume) / sum(volume)
from table
group by date, hour
```

Having an index on (date, hour) or at least date, will help.

Comment: specifically: CREATE INDEX ix_temporal ON table (date, hour) INCLUDE (price, volume)